# fscanf with 2 files and multiple lines

Tags: c, scanf

I am attempting to build a circuit simulator out of 2 text files, one containing the circuit description and another the values.

Ex circuit:

```
 INPUTVAR 3 A B C
 OUTPUTVAR 1 Q
 AND A B w
 AND A C x
 OR w x Q
```

so this creates the circuit: w = A.B; x = A.C; and Q = w +x;
Inputvar has the format where it is followed by an int, then that many chars corresponding to the names of variables, same for Outputvar.

ex input:

```
 1 0 1
 0 0 1
```

I am trying to read in the first line of the input then read the first 2 lines of the circuit file to populate an array with those corresponding values at the indices.

```
 FILE *circuit, *input;
 input = fopen(argv[2],"r");
 int upper[26],output[26]; //upper is array of all upper letters, output is same.
 char str1[10],str2[10];
 int i,numin,numout;

 while(!feof(input)
 {
 circuit = fopen(argv[1],"r");
 fscanf(circuit("%s %d ", str1, &numin);
 //this works correctly and gets INPUTVAR then 3.
 for(i = 0; i <numin; i++)
 fscanf(input,"%d ",&upper[i]);
 fscanf(circuit,"%s %d ",str2,&numout);
 //does not work correctly
 }
```

After populating the array with the input variables I am trying to get how many outputs and their names and then populating that corresponding array (output) with a temp number to store for later use. I am using fscanf because I have a specified format for each of the type of "circuit blocks".

How do I get it to also read the 2nd line in the circuit.txt? After I do that then I have to read the rest of the lines to "create" the circuit.

Comment: Do not use `while(!feof(input)`  Check the result of `fscanf()` to know when to exit loop.

Comment: If you really want fault tolerant code, read each and every line with `fgets()` and then parse.  If parsing with `sscanf()`, check its results.

Answer (score 1):

The line `fscanf(circuit("%s %d ", str1, &numin);` reads INPUTVAR and 3 of this line: INPUTVAR 3 A B C.   However, the next read will get A B C.   You need to read these items to skip over them and get to the next line.

Comment: %*[^\n] I addded this, and it seems to work. Now I just have to figure out how to "build" the circuit.